Array from C# code in unity is not showing up in the inspector
So, this is exactly what's going on. I have code inside of a C# file in Unity, basically getting the spawn points I set and spawn enemies in there. So, obviously, I'd have an array for all of the spawn locations so the code can recognize where to spawn the enemies (you'd think). The array does not show up in the unity inspector. Someone help? I'm a beginner in C# so I apologize if anything is stupid.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnObject;
    public GameObject[] spawnPoints;
    public float timer;
    public float timeBetweenSpawns;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > timeBetweenSpawns)
        {
            timer = 0;
            int randomNum = Random.Range(0, 3);
            Instantiate(spawnObject, spawnPoints[randomNum].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}


Do you mean the spawnPoints array? Is there still an error in your editor? Perhaps the GameManager hasn't been compiled yet, so the array isn't visible.

Try add "[SerializeField]" on top of your array declaration and see if anything changes

Can you also provide a screenshot of your inspector, showing the GameManager component

@PavlosMavris that's specifically for serializing fields that are non-public .. so this won't change anything here ;)

@derHugo Yes, I know. But also, Unity might have a bug, and that resolves it, so you don't have anything to lose when it comes to breaking down an issue. Always remember that.

This is the results when I re-create your code.

As comments have pointed out it's likely your script isn't being re-compiled due to an error somewhere else in your project. This should be visible in the unity editor console.
Code:
using UnityEngine;

namespace Player
{
    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject spawnObject;
        public GameObject[] spawnPoints;
        public float timer;
        public float timeBetweenSpawns;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        private void Start()
        {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer > timeBetweenSpawns)
            {
                timer = 0;
                var randomNum = Random.Range(0, 3);
                Instantiate(spawnObject, spawnPoints[randomNum].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}

